# Some Django ChoiceFields with the same choice source

Tags: python, django, choicefield

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    DAYS = ((str(d), str(d)) for d in range(1, 29))

    day1 = models.CharField('Day 1', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=DAYS)
    day2 = models.CharField('Day 2', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=DAYS)
```

After it gets rendered I see that only field `day1` has choice list, but `day2` is empty. If I make another constant `DAYS2` with the same definition and assign it to `day2` - it works.

It seems Django modifies the source of `choices` argument? I did not find it in the sources, but maybe I do something wrong? Is it a known limitation?

I can use workaround of applying `deepcopy` on `DAYS`. But I do not think it is good style. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list for `DAYS`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    DAYS = [str(d), str(d)) for d in range(1, 29)]
    day1 = models.CharField('Day 1', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=DAYS)
    day2 = models.CharField('Day 2', max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=DAYS)
```

Currently, `DAYS` is a generator. When you access it the first time to get choices for `day1`, it returns the results you expect. However, the generator has then been consumed, so you get an empty list when you try to get the choices for `day2`.

You can see this by trying the following in the Python shell:

```
>>> DAYS = ((str(d), str(d)) for d in range(1,5))
>>> print(list(DAYS))
[('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3'), ('4', '4')]
>>> print(list(DAYS))
[]
>>>
```